# React Native error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(dataBlob[sectionID])')

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

I'm trying to display facebook page status in React Native application with facebook API in a ListView. [This tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html) helpd me a lot and I managed to display the last status in my application.

But when I tried to put all the status in the ListView I get this error message : "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Object.keys(dataBlob[sectionID])')"

I read in another stackoverflow post that it was because I tried to 
run cloneWithRows() function on an object instead of an Array. But I still can't manage to get over this error.

So if someone can help me that would be great. Here is a sample of the JSON generated by facebook API

```
{"data":[{"message":"Test","created_time":"2016-05-31T13:36:56+0000","id":"1602039116775292_1605827029729834"},

{"message":"Hello","created_time":"2016-05-31T13:36:50+0000","id":"1602039116775292_1605827006396503"},
```

And this is some of my index.ios.js file :

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(){
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.timeline), //The problem is here
          loaded: true,
        });
      })
      .done();
  }

  render(){
    if (!this.state.timelines) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return(
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderStatus}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
```

In this line :

```
dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.timeline),
```

I tried to replace 'timeline' with 'data' but that don't load the data and keep on LoadingView.

If you need more code or information let me know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is in `responseData.timeline`? Or for that matter `responseData` itself?

Comment: @TomWalters I used responseData.timeline because i followed the tutorial I mensionned previously but normally it contain the data get with the fetch call to my facebook API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out what was wrong with my code. 
The error came from render function when I check if this.stat.timelines is set. But in this case 'timelines' doesn't exist.

```
if (!this.state.loaded) {
  return this.renderLoadingView();
}
```

This is how I fixed it.